# replace digits from text

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a text file I need to replace digits with white space.

I tried splitting the text file first into individual words and then checked if that word is digit or not

```
   def replace_digits_symbols():
    text_file = open_file()
    for word in text_file:
       for char in word:
         if char.isdigit():
             word.replace(char, " ")
      print(text_file)
```

it should replace them with white spaces but nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

The `str.replace` method simply returns the replaced string without altering the original string in-place, which is why calling `word.replace(char, " ")` does nothing. You can instead use `str.join` with a generator expression that iterates through each character in a line and outputs a space instead of the original character if it is a digit:

```
with open('file') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(''.join(' ' if char.isdigit() else char for char in line))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for this process,

```
def helper(text):
    import string
    for digit in string.digits:
        text = text.replace(digit, ' ')
    return text

def ReplaceDigits(fileName):
    output_file = open("processed.txt",'w')
    lineNo = 1
    with open(fileName) as file_ptr:
        for lines in file_ptr:
            print("Processing Line No : {}".format(lineNo))
            lines = helper(lines)
            output_file.write(lines)
            lineNo +=1
ReplaceDigits("test.txt")
```

test.txt contains

```
this1is5sample0text
this10is552sample0text
this10is5sample0text
this10is52sample0text
this0is52sample0text
```

and the result is,

```
this is sample text
this  is   sample text
this  is sample text
this  is  sample text
this is  sample text
```